# Phalcon: Notice Undefined Variable in the Scaffold-generated views (model and the controller are fine)

Tags: php, view, model, phalcon

I have generate a model using the `scaffold` comment, and here's part the model, just to make sure that the database is connected:

```
<?php

class Member extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

    /**
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $firstname;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $surname;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $membertype;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $dateofbirth;

    /**
     * Initialize method for model.
     */
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSchema("db_mvq");
        $this->setSource("Member");
    }
```

Then I get these errors:

http://prntscr.com/n907hb

Every time I open the search page created by the `scaffold` command, here's the part of the view concerned with this:

```
<?php foreach ($page->items as $member): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $Member->id ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Member->firstname ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Member->surname ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Member->membertype ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Member->dateofbirth ?></td>
```

I don't understand. What's wrong here?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: can you state the phalcon-dev tools version. this could be a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the foreach has lowercase variable name

and inside the block first letter is uppercase

change `$Member` to `$member`

```
<?php foreach ($page->items as $member): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $member->id ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $member->firstname ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $member->surname ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $member->membertype ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $member->dateofbirth ?></td>
```